# How to represent QED (not as a box!) the way Tim Roughgarden did?

Tags: proof-package

I'm trying to write QED as written in the image below. I searched the entire palette in the latexit application but couldn't find any. I tried \textit{QED} but that is just QED in italics.

Anyone know how to do this?

[image: Tim Roughgarden's QED]

Comment: Why not use the greek version (`EOΔ`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try mathcal or mathscr. Should be one of them, depending on the font.